# When do I have to use plt.show()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)  
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))

df_new.plot(kind='bar')
```

I have no idea about weather I have to use `plt.show()` or not. Because if there is only `df_new.plot(kind='bar')`,it will shows the plot. If I add `plot.show()`,it shows also. What is the difference between them? I use Jupyter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the IDE. Is this Jupyter or something else? There are lots of things you might want to do before the figure is displayed, but I guess something else is smart enough to know that the script has ended and you want a plot in your plot window

Comment: By default you need `plt.show`, but some environments (newer ipython and jupyter among others) automatically enable interactive mode (`plt.ion()`) for you, which implies you _don't_ have to call this to get your figures. See also [the official FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode)

Answer (score 2):

I guess your using interactive tool like jupyter.
In case of jupyter as you said  `df.plot(kind ='bar')`  displays the graph.
In interactive tools, You need to use `plt.show()` when all your plots are created.

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  plt.plot(x, y)
  plt.plot(y,z)
  plt.show()
```

In python IDLE if you just use `df.plot((kind = 'bar')`, it won't displays the graph on run.
To display the graph without using `plt.show()` in IDLE you can follow the following steps.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib import interactive
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 #Set interactive mode to True
 interactive(True)
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns = list('ABC'))
 df.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, without the `plt.show()`, the figure doesn't show. I think it depends on what IDE you are using. So please use the `plt.show()` for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

df_new.plot(kind='bar') will  instantiate  and return object of plt, something like:"", so you have to call plt.show() for this object to see your plot. Here is what happen when you call plt.show(); show() function will draw plot property of the last created object of plt. Hope it helps.

Comment: The reason you see the figure in jupyter is that in jupyter you will see the result of the last operation executed  in your code snippet, for example: if you write 7+5 as the last line of your code snippet and execute your code 12 will be displayed as result although you didn't write print(7+5).